# Erro na validação de XSD

Tags: java, xsd

Meu XSD após algumas modificações por uma outra equipe começou a dar o erro:

```
Parse Error at line 33 column 14: s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_TxnHdrTransaction' is invalid.  Element 'any' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

Meu código do XSD é o seguinte:

```
<xs:element name="TxnHdr">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:any>
                    <xs:element name="TxnID" type="x:NumericVar15" />
                    <xs:element name="LogTxnID" type="x:NumericVar15" />
                    <xs:element name="MediaBalance" type="x:NumericVar8" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnDate" type="x:NumericFixed14" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnExtRef" type="x:AlphaNumericVar50" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnTypeX" type="x:NumericVar2" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnMode" type="x:NumericFixed1" />
                    <xs:element name="VoidStatus" type="x:NumericFixed1" />
                    <xs:element name="FailedStatus" type="x:NumericFixed1" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnSourceX" type="x:NumericVar2" />
                    <xs:element name="PurchAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="DiscAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="RdmAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="AdjAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="MediaTxnSeq" type="x:NumericVar3" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:any>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Como funciona o `<any>`

O problema nesse caso é que a tag [`<any>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043(v=vs.110).aspx) está sendo usada de forma incorreta. No XSD transparece a ideia de que a tag poderia ser qualquer coisa, desde que mantendo a estrutura dos filhos, mas não é assim que funciona.

A ideia do `<any>` é dizer que num determinado ponto o XML pode ser estendido, mas não se define ali qual a estrutura.

## Exemplo

No [exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp) a seguir, define-se a tag `pessoa`, incluindo `primeiroNome`, `ultimoNome` e então a tag `any` permite acrescentar um elemento adicional qualquer:

```xml
<xs:element name="pessoa">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="primeiroNome" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="ultimoNome" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Continuando o exemplo, pode-se definir então um XSD de um elemento `filhos`

```xml
<xs:element name="filhos">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nome" type="xs:string"
      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Então, um XLS válido para esse XSD poderia conter a seguinte estrutura:

```xml
<pessoa>
  <primeiroNome>João</primeiroNome>
  <ultimoNome>Ferreira</ultimoNome>
  <filhos>
    <nome>Gabriel</nome>
  </filhos>
</pessoa>
```

Note que, ao invés de `filhos`, poderíamos ter qualquer outra tag definida neste ou em outro XSD.

## Ou use apenas `<xs:sequence>`

Caso a ideia não seja ter um elemento genérico como descrito acima, basta trocar a tag `<xs:any>` por `<xs:sequence>`.

Fiz alguns testes usando um [validador online](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) e improvisei algumas informações que faltam no XSD da pergunta. Cheguei ao seguinte XSD válido:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:element name="TxnHdr">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TxnID" type="x:NumericVar15" />
                    <xs:element name="LogTxnID" type="x:NumericVar15" />
                    <xs:element name="MediaBalance" type="x:NumericVar8" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnDate" type="x:NumericFixed14" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnExtRef" type="x:AlphaNumericVar50" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnTypeX" type="x:NumericVar2" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnMode" type="x:NumericFixed1" />
                    <xs:element name="VoidStatus" type="x:NumericFixed1" />
                    <xs:element name="FailedStatus" type="x:NumericFixed1" />
                    <xs:element name="TxnSourceX" type="x:NumericVar2" />
                    <xs:element name="PurchAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="DiscAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="RdmAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="AdjAmt" type="x:NegPositiveDecimalVar21_4" />
                    <xs:element name="MediaTxnSeq" type="x:NumericVar3" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Entendi, Luiz! Eu já havia feito as alterações e consertado aqui, mas sua explicação me ajudou a esclarecer um pouco as coisas! XSD é um pouco confuso rs! Obrigado!